# How to use TestDisk

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIfGn.jpg)

I just replaced my Windows 10 and switched to Ubuntu and deleted all my data accidently as it was in partitions on my windows.Tried using TestDisk for its recovery after reading forum and I found my two lost partitions listed in the search.How can I recover it? Can I write their data to my Laptop's HDD as currently I am in Live session or do I have to use some bigger space external storage as the data is very huge(around 500 GB) or Can I shift it in bits using 32 GB USB?

Answer (score 2):

Learning an application means sometimes reading its documentation. The developers have a [step by step tutorial](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) on how to proceed with it.

A search for "testdisk tutorial" in your favorite web search engine will yield more resources, including videos.

> Can I write their data to my Laptop's HDD as currently I am in Live session or do I have to use some bigger space external storage as the data is very huge(around 500 GB) or Can I shift it in bits using 32 GB USB?

Any attempt to write on a disk where data are lost will further decrease the chance of successfully recovering some data.

**Testdisk** is capable of recovering whipped partitions. If the partitions themselves have not been overwritten, there is a chance that the file system can be read again, thus the files recovered. If the partitions have partially been overwritten, some files will be intact, but other files will be corrupt.

If no file system is retrieved, then the accompanying program **Photorec** can recognize usable files in the blob of binary data that your disk still has in the absence of usable file system structures. Do not hold your breath: that tool recovers a number of files and gives them random names. It is then up to the user to check each of these recovered files, rename and classify them again one by one and delete the ones that are corrupted.

Professional data recovery services may do a better job in recovering data, but this is very expensive.

*There is essentially no other viable option than to have spare copies of user data* when you are working with computers. Some learn this the hard way (I did, albeit that was still the time of 5 inch floppy disks).